# trying to create Favorite Button for add items in favorite list

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to create favorite button on CollectionViewCell for saving items in favorite list. When i tapped on favorite icon button it successfully add selected cell item in array of favorite list class, and also shows in favorite list. When i tapped on favorite button it change its image according to values are already saved or not. 
When i'm trying to save favorite list array in NSUserDefaults it save and also show values when i retrieve it. But when i close my app from simulator and run again it not shows values in favorite list array that i saved in NSUserDefaults and also want to set button image state according to item already add or not.

[Output](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B29ka7gbDAYxbkRqa29aZWh0dWM) When i tapped on favorite. And run again after closing my App.
Can anyone tell me how i can fix that. Or can anyone please fix it in my [project.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B29ka7gbDAYxVHlHb3dZcGlTV0U)
Thanks

```
import UIKit

var url : [NSString] = [
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9h30Bx4Klxg",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ij_0p_6qTss",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJtDXIazrMo",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H202k7KfZL0",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGyEd0aKWZE",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AtKZKl7Bgu0",
    "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4SYlLi5djz0"]

var image : [NSString] = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg", "5.jpg", "6.jpg", "7.jpg"]


class LiveCollectionView: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource,UIWebViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
        UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return url.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LiveCollectionViewCell

        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: image[indexPath.row] as String)
        cell.playBt.addTarget(self, action: Selector("webView:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

        cell.playBt.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.heartBt.tag = indexPath.row

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    }
}
```

---

```
import UIKit

class LiveCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell{

var showPlayButton = true

var number = Int()
var secondNumber = Int()

@IBOutlet weak var playBt: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var heartBt: UIButton!

@IBAction func heartBt(sender: UIButton) {


    var btn : NSInteger
    btn = sender.tag as NSInteger

    let uValues = url[btn]
    let iValues = image[btn]

    if showPlayButton == true{
        u.append(url[btn])
        i.append(image[btn])

        self.heartBt.setImage(UIImage(named: "rheart"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        showPlayButton = false
        print("rHeart xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")

    }else{

        for check in u {

            number++
            print(number)

            if uValues == check{
                print(u)
                u.removeAtIndex(number-1)
                number = 0
                print("RemoVe at indext path")
                print(u)
                break

            }

        }

        for check2 in i{

            secondNumber++
            print(secondNumber)

            if iValues == check2{
                print(i)
                i.removeAtIndex(secondNumber-1)
                secondNumber = 0
                print("RemoVe at indext path")
                print(i)
                self.heartBt.setImage(UIImage(named: "wHeart"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
                showPlayButton = true
                print("wHeart ........")
                break

            }

        }

    }

}
}
```

---

```
import UIKit
var u : [NSString] = []
var i : [NSString] = []
class FavoriteTvViewController: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDelegate{
    var uV : NSArray = []
    var iV : NSArray = []

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    let reuseIdentifier = "cell"

    override func viewDidLoad(){
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        collectionView.reloadData()
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(u, forKey: "u")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(i, forKey: "i")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

        uV = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("u") as! NSArray
        iV = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("i") as! NSArray
        print("uV values.. \(uV)")
        print("iV values.. \(iV)")
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return uV.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> FavoriteTvCollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FavoriteTvCollectionViewCell

        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: iV[indexPath.row] as! String)
        return cell
    }
}
```

---

```
import UIKit
class FavoriteTvCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
}
```

Comment: Please upload the images to SO rather than sharing in google drive (links might be broken a few months ago but people will see the question unless you delete it)

Comment: My profile reputation is less then to 10 how i can upload on SO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had Checked your sample project,I made a small change now it's working fine.

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    collectionView.reloadData()
    //You have check for availablity of favorute item before adding to userdefault 
    if u.count > 0 {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(u, forKey: "u")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(i, forKey: "i")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }


    uV = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("u")!
    iV = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("i")!
    print("uV values.. \(uV)")
    print("iV values.. \(iV)")
}
```

Check availability of object before adding it to Userdefault.Now its working fine give it a try and let me know the response pls.

**EDIT:**
I have edited your code now it is working fine,I hear by list out all those changes done by me.

1. In **LiveCollectionView.swift**:

   Declaring two objects and In viewdidload:

   ```
     var MutableArray:NSMutableArray!
     let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()


     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

         MutableArray = NSMutableArray()
         if let HaveUrl = defaults.objectForKey("u"){
            u = HaveUrl.mutableCopy() as! [NSString]
         }
         if let HaveImage = defaults.objectForKey("i"){
            i = HaveImage.mutableCopy() as! [NSString]
         }


        if let CheckAvailability = defaults.objectForKey("Fav_Unfav"){
           MutableArray = CheckAvailability.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableArray
        }else{
        for var Check in image {
           print(Check)
           MutableArray.addObject("wHeart")
        }
     }
   }
   ```

   cellForItemAtIndexPath:

   ```
   //Add this New Line
   cell.heartBt.setImage(UIImage(named: MutableArray[indexPath.row] as! String), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
   ```
2. **LiveCollectionViewCell.swift:**

   ```
    class LiveCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell{

    var showPlayButton = true

    var number = Int()
    var secondNumber = Int()

    @IBOutlet weak var playBt: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var heartBt: UIButton!

    @IBAction func heartBt(sender: UIButton) {


   var btn : NSInteger
   btn = sender.tag as NSInteger

   let uValues = url[btn]
   let iValues = image[btn]

   if MutableArray[btn] as! String == "rheart" {
       showPlayButton = false
   }

   if showPlayButton == true{
       //Add this Line
       MutableArray.replaceObjectAtIndex(btn, withObject: "rheart")

       u.append(url[btn])
       i.append(image[btn])
       self.heartBt.setImage(UIImage(named: "rheart"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
       showPlayButton = false
       print("rHeart xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")

   }else{
       //Add this Line
       MutableArray.replaceObjectAtIndex(btn, withObject: "wHeart")

       for check in u {

           number++
           print(number)

           if uValues == check{
               print(u)
               u.removeAtIndex(number-1)
               number = 0
               print("RemoVe at indext path")
               print(u)

               break

           }

       }

       for check2 in i{

           secondNumber++
           print(secondNumber)

           if iValues == check2{
               print(i)
               i.removeAtIndex(secondNumber-1)
               secondNumber = 0
               print("RemoVe at indext path")
               print(i)
               self.heartBt.setImage(UIImage(named: "wHeart"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
               showPlayButton = true
               print("wHeart ........")
               break

           }

       }

   }
      //Set the array to userdefault
       defaults.setObject(MutableArray, forKey: "Fav_Unfav")
       defaults.setObject(u, forKey: "u")
       defaults.setObject(i, forKey: "i")

       defaults.synchronize()
      }
   }
   ```
3. **FavoriteTvViewController.swift:**

   ```
   override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
      collectionView.reloadData()

      if let CheckURL = defaults.objectForKey("u") {
        uV = CheckURL.mutableCopy() as! NSArray
      }

      if let CheckImage = defaults.objectForKey("i"){
        iV = CheckImage.mutableCopy() as! NSArray
      }

      print("uV values.. \(uV)")
      print("iV values.. \(iV)")
   }
   ```