# NSUserDefaults save values but not show values after quite and running again app Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsuserdefaults

I am appending values on (u,i) from my favorite button of another class. I save (u,i) in NSUserDefaults and retrieve values successfully but when i quite application and run again, (u,i) not shows any values?
Can anyone tell me how i can fix that. Or can anyone please fix it in my [project.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B29ka7gbDAYxVHlHb3dZcGlTV0U)
Thanks

```
import UIKit
var u : [NSString] = []
var i : [NSString] = []
class FavoriteTvViewController: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDelegate{
    var uV : NSArray = []
    var iV : NSArray = []

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!


    let reuseIdentifier = "cell"

    override func viewDidLoad(){
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        collectionView.reloadData()
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(u, forKey: "u")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(i, forKey: "i")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

        uV = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("u") as! NSArray
        iV = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("i") as! NSArray

        print("uV values.. \(uV)")
        print("iV values.. \(iV)")
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return uV.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> FavoriteTvCollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FavoriteTvCollectionViewCell

        cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: iV[indexPath.row] as! String)
        return cell
    }


}
```

Comment: Try with ObjectForKey Instead of arrayForKey

Comment: Use NSUserDefaults .standardUserDefaults().valueForKey(key!)

Comment: I think you have posted your question twice with some modification,Check [MyAnswer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37429380/trying-to-create-favorite-button-for-add-items-in-favorite-list/37433055#37433055).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How your code works :

- declare u and assign to it [] (empty array)
- set NSUserDefault u (an empty array)
- retrieve the value of NSUserDefault

the problem is : each time you start the app , you save an empty array before getting the value in NSUserDefault

Comment: I declare `u` empty because i append values on it from another class, and when i append values on it, it show values when i retrieve it on `uV`. The main problem is that when i quite application and run again it did't show append values that i saved on NSUserFefaults? What you say where i can declare `u` from prevent it to save empty. Or can you please fix it in my project.

Comment: the problem is that you save the array in viewWillAppear so each time you start the app , you save an empty array erasing your previous Data.